# What is the preferred way to regularly export data from SAP to other software?

Tags: export, data-science, hana

Currently, for a data science project, I have to access customer data located within an SAP system (Hana). My idea is to configure SAP so that the data is regularly exported to a folder and processed from there. For an optimal implementation it is important that the data is exported regularly.

Unfortunately, I have little experience with SAP. What is the "Way-To-Go" for exporting data from SAP to a tabular format for further use in other applications? Is this something that the customer can set up, or does an application have to be developed in SAP?

Comment: Depends on the data and how you want them. There are things which can be exported easily without development, but some things need to be developed.

Comment: You either have to develop custom endpoints in SAP to expose the data, or you use tools to extract the data to CSV file or database. If you can access HANA DB directly, you can easily write SQL statement, or you can use free tool like AecorSoft Reporting HANA Edition (our tool) to bring HANA data into Excel. Otherwise, if you can only access SAP application layer, then you will need some help from other external tools (we also have commercial tool)

Comment: What applications are you trying to connect to?